# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' || related to django user creation

Tags: django

I am getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

This is my code:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
seld.uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()`
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Django 2.2, `urlsafe_base64_encode` returns a string instead of bytes, so you should no longer call the `decode` method anymore:

```
seld.uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
```